# hide Shared Files Alfresco Share enterprise 4.2

Tags: javascript, alfresco

As described in https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-19930 I tried option 3 of using the javascript function in share-header.get.js file however I am seeing error that Object.prototype.toString().apply is not a function.

Could some one please let me know how to hide Shared Files option from Alfresco share. I am using Alfresco Enterprise 4.2

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me. Try

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas for the clue. There was a reference somewhere else about the correction, however I could not notice it in the clutter untill I saw your single line!! May be because its v.late at night at my end :)